# How to use UIImagePickerController in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get image from camera or photo library and use an `UIImageView` to preview that photo.
I use the code below to capture image :

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.delegate = self
picker.sourceType = .camera
present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and then I use this code to put image in imageView :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

I get  permission and the app load successfully on my IPhone 
but when I capture a picture it doesn't go back to main View to show on image view .
and it crash .
can any body help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dismiss end of the function `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
picker.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil)
```